# How do I #define an unsigned char* string?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, unsigned-char, signedness

I have following define in my code

```
#define PRODUCTNAME     "SomeName"
```

and I want to send it with a function `com_reply(unsigned char* msg, uint16_t lenght)`.

Now I get a warning that my argument differs in signedness. I know what the problem is and also why `com_reply` uses `unsigned char*` instead of `char*`, I just want to know:

How can I define my string as an `unsigned char*` so I can use it throughout my program without getting warnings all over the place.

EDIT:

Strictly speaking I have more than one defines here and the main reason is that there is a `BANNER` define which consists of several other defines, like this:

```
#define PRODUCTNAME     "SomeName"
#define PRODUCTDATE     "2013-03-30"
#define BANNER          PRODUCTNAME " (" PRODUCTDATE ")"
```

Should I create const variables and concatenate them at program start instead of using defines here?

Comment: Why not `const char* PRODUCTNAME = "SomeName"` or similar? (unrelated, but #define has plenty of disadvantages for this.)

Comment: I dunno how standard-compliant this is, but what about: `(const unsigned char*)"SomeName"`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the `com_reply` function do?  It seems like it's something that shouldn't actually take a string, but rather a pointer to a number between 0 and 255.

Comment: `com_reply` is used to send all kind of things, mostly binary data, sometimes human readable strings. that's why it takes `unsigned char*`

Comment: Does `com_reply` declare its parameters `const`? If not, you'll get a warning sending one.

Comment: No, the definition is just like i put it here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
#define PRODUCTNAME     ((const unsigned char *)"SomeName")
```

Comment: Never assign (or cast whatever) string literals to non-const pointers

Comment: Non-const is correct, since a string literal is not `const`. But it implies you can modify it, which you can't.

Comment: I believe this is the first time I've seen a post with 3 or more downvotes which are all removed after an edit. That's amazing.

Comment: Should be a badge for that!